# python, use try/except in dictionary to avoid errors

Tags: python

I have a dict like `{'key1': fun1(...), 'key2': fun2(...), ...}` and this functions could raise errors (undefined), is there a way to use try/except to create the dictionary?

Comment: Can you explain how do you build the dictionary? Where are keyx and funx coming from?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper function like this:

```
def or_default(v, f, *args, **kw):
     try:
         return f(*args, **kw)
     except:
         return v
```

Then initialize your dictionary this way:

```
{'key1': or_default(42, fun1, ...), 'key2': or_default('something', fun2, ...), ...}
```

Essentially what we're doing here is *decorating* the functions to return a default value if they raise an exception. You can make this even simpler if you want to use the same default value for all the functions (say, `None`), just have `or_default` return that value in the `except` block and get rid of the `v` parameter.

The reason we have to do it in this way, using a function, is that `try`/`except` is not an expression in Python. Other languages do have that as an expression (Kotlin, basically every functional language that supports exceptions), so in those languages you would just use `try`/`except` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to either wrap the whole dictionary creation in a try/except block, or, if you can modify the functions, put the code parts of the functions that could raise errors in try/except blocks.